# Rails 4 Relationship Status Method, Is This Optimal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a social site in Rails 4. Users can request to follow another user.

In my user model I have the following method. It works but I'm wondering if it is the best way to do determine the relationship status. Will this scale okay?

Thanks.

```
def relationship_status(user_2)
  relationship = Relationship.where(follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user_2.id)
  unless relationship.any?
    relationship = Relationship.where(followed_id: self.id, follower_id: user_2.id)
    unless relationship.any?
      return "not_friends"
    else
      if relationship.first.status == "pending"
        return "pending_recieved"
      elsif  relationship.first.status == "ignored"
        return "you_ignored"
      elsif relationship.first.status == "active"
        return "your_followed"
      end
    end
  else
    if relationship.first.status == "pending"
      return "pending_sent"
    elsif relationship.first.status == "ignored"
      return "your_ignored"
    elsif relationship.first.status == "active"
      return "you_are_following"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you have a bug in your code.  Both of the `relationship`s you've defined are the same!

Comment: The where clause is reversed. follower_id and followed_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this will scale very well as you will have to check each relationship for each operation.  The better approach would be to fan them out and scope them for faster queries

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_relationships, dependent:destroy, inverse_of :user
  has_many :users, through: user_relationships
  has_many :affected_user_relationships, class_name: UserRelatonship, dependent:destroy, foreign_key :affected_id
  has_many :affected_users, through: user_relationships, source: :affected_user

  has_many :ignored_relationships, dependent:destroy, inverse_of :user
  has_many :ignored_users, through: ignored_relationships

  # etc... 
end

class UserRelationship
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :affected_user, class_name: User

  validates_presence_of :user, :affected_user
end

class IgnoredRelationship < UserRelationship
end

class FollowedRelationship < UserRelationship
end
```

Then you could do faster queries.

```
def ignored?(u)
  self.ignored_users.include?(u)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing glaringly bad here that will prevent you from scaling with respect to performance. The bigger scaling issue is your code's clarity, and how much you'll hate yourself when you need to make a change here 4 months from now, but can't remember what the hell you were trying to do here.

First, you should probably extract the logic that determine the nature of relationship into methods on your Relationship class:

```
class Relationship
  def following_status
    case status
    when 'pending'
     'pending_sent'
    when 'ignored'
     'your_ignored'
    when 'active'
     'you_are_following'
    end
  end

  def followed_status
    case status
    when 'pending_received'
     'pending_sent'
    when 'you_ignored'
     'your_ignored'
    when 'active'
     'you_followed'
    end
  end
end
```

Then we can clean up the relationship status method using more meaningful variable names:

```
def relationship_status(other_user)
  if following = Relationship.where(follower_id: self.id, followed_id: other_user.id).first
   return following.following_status
  end
  if followed = Relationship.where(followed_id: self.id, follower_id: other_user.id).first
    return followed.followed_status
  end
  'not_friends'
end
```

Aside: [Don't use `unless` and `else` together.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless) That form reads rather poorly, and gets very dizzying, especially in nested statements.